# Grouped gallery content with Views

Tags: 7, views

I have an gallery content type with a title-, image-, and text select list field. This content type is used for a gallery where the select list values works as a kind of category for the gallery(a bit like a taxonomy). Using Views I have gotten all the published values printed out group according to there select list values. However I would like to print out an headline above each of the grouped images. Like this:

headline1

item1, item2, item3...

headline2

item4, item5, item6...

The headline is one of the values from the select list field and the grouped items below is the content where this specific value is chosen from the select list field(during upload). Its easy to get stuff printed out and sorted using Views but it seems to be more difficult to get and headline in there.

Anyone know if this is possible, maybe using preprocess for views or views-view.tpl.php files? I have gotten this to work with the grouping feature for table layout, but would like to have it printed out in unformatted html instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should already be happening. Which version of Views?

If, as you said, the headlines ARE the values of the select list, then they should be showing up above each group automatically.

In Views 3:
Under Fields, add the select_list_field and check "Exclude from display"
Under Style settings (unformatted), choose Grouping Field: select_list_field

It will group by the select list item, and display that select list item's name (ie, the headline) above the group.

Comment: Thx, i got it now. Also found semantic views pretty useful:).